# FTP failed with Inet control - State 11 (icError)

Tags: ftp, vb6, inet

i'm working with VB6 and i need download a file by FTP.

Then i use INet control.

In my machine, the FTP run and download a file without problems.
But in another machine don't run. This machine works with Windows 10.

I have reviewed Windows Defender and Windows Firewall and I do not see anything wrong.

my code is

```
Origen = Fichero1 & ".xml"
Destino = PathDatos & "FicherosEvo\" & Fichero1 & ".xml"
Url = "ftp://ftp.myweb.com/"
ITCComunidadEvo2.protocol = icFTP
ITCComunidadEvo2.Url = Url 
ITCComunidadEvo2.UserName = "xxxxx" 
ITCComunidadEvo2.Cancel
ITCComunidadEvo2.Password = "yyyyy"  
ITCComunidadEvo2.RequestTimeout = 400

ITCComunidadEvo2.Execute , "GET " & Chr(34) & Origen & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Destino & Chr(34)
```

The state of ITCComunidadEvo2 (The Inet control) finished with State 11 (icError)

any suggestions??? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean that it "Don't run"? Do you get an error? What are the symptoms you see?

Comment: i can see the states of ITCComunidadEvo2 (The Inet control). And always finished with State 11 (icError)

Comment: The previous states are 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11. And i can see with ITCComunidadEvo2_StateChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the problem.

The path "Destino", was not created